# Currency format as “£##,##0.00”

Tags: c#

I need the currency Format as `“£##,##0.00”`...use this but no one is working.

```
string str1 = string.Format("£##,##0.00", value);
string str3= String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", value);
string str2 = string.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);''}", value);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture()` one can set the culture information, and thereby adjust to the country and print out the price with the proper money currency symbol.

link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture.aspx

```
decimal price = 9565.50m; 
string total = string.Format(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"), "{0:C}", price);
```